# Pivot Table be able to do calculation based on a column value

Tags: pivot

I would like to know if it is possible to do a calculated field based on a formula taking into account the value of a column.

For example  I have a column giving me 2 value L or B
For each of my product MM, 000150KP, 000270 KS ... I would like to retrieve an agregated result of the quantity which is the substraction of the B minus the L.
My pivot table is givin me this result:
The calculated field column is the result i would like to retrieve by using a special formula but i don t know how to do it...

```
Row Labels       :   Sum qty ABS    : Calculated field?s
* MM             :        1200      :     1200
  B              :        1200      :
* 000150KP       :        2000      :   -20000
   L             :        2000      :
* 000270 KS      :        739400    :   -450600
  B              :        144400    :
  L              :       595000     : 
* 000660 KS      :        591550    :     5915500
  B              :        591550    :
```

For example on MM it will give me 1200 in the calculated new qty
On the 000150kP it will give me -2000 in the calculated new qty
on 000270 KS item it would give me 144400-595000 = -450600 in the calculated new qty
Pleqse see above the description to be more clear

Many thanks for your help
Olivier

Comment: Is there a technical question here? What programming/scripting language are you using?

Comment: Hello Ellesedil, this is  excel pivot table and if i had to code something it would be with vba.